# How to fix header height and resize logo with CSS in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menubar

This is my [website.](http://agilmar.com) I work with Wordpress and my theme is Sonata (Themeforest).

At some point I made some tweaks to the menu bar height on the CSS code, but now I want to make it smaller again (more proportionate). 
Also, I would like to make the logo responsive, so that it fits within the menu bar.

Can somebody help me with the CSS code?
I don't know what part of the code should I modify, but I believe it is this one (correct me if it is not):

---

```
/* Header
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#wi-header {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:9999;
    transition:height .3s ease-out;
    }
#wi-header .container {
    position:relative;
    }   
#wi-logo a {
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    font-size:34px;
    font-family:"Oswald", sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin:0;
    height:auto;
    }
#wi-logo img {
    max-height:auto;
    display:block;
    class:img-responsive;
    }   
.site-description {
    color:#999;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-top:10px;
    }
.site-description a {
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
```

---

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added style="position:absolute; height:100%;" to an img tag and it got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tweak your lay-out, I suggest you start learning HTML & CSS. That said, your logo is taking the width of its parent element, i.e. `<div class="span4">`. So your logo has a width of 100% compared to this div. One solution could be:

```
#wi-logo img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

which will make your logo the half of the width of its parent. But there are multiple possibilities, depending on what you really want. Again, I suggest you learn the basics. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/) is a great place to start.

**Edit:**

In most cases, the best thing you can do if you wan't to modify a theme, is to create a child theme. It's never good practice to modify code of an existing theme. When it gets updated, you might lose your changes. Take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes. The short answer: create a child theme with at least a `style.css` file in and make your changes there. The style.css should contain at least this comments at the top of it:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Your Child Theme Name
 Template:     Sonata
*/
```

Where `Template` is the parent theme, Sonata in your case. Then, choose your theme as the theme for your site in the backend.

Last but not least: imho, you shouldn't modify the css for the span div. Most likely this is part of a (grid) framework like Foundation or so, which has probably a lay-out of 12 columns, where span-4 means 4/12 of 100% of the width. That's the default structure and isn't meant to be changed. But go on and experiment.

Comment: Hi Thomas_inckx, thanks for your prompt reply! If the logo is already responsive from its parent element, then what I really want is to change the parent (the main navigation/menu bar). I know the basics of HTML & CSS but still get lost with the strings. Which one is the code string where I should modify that?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope this makes it clear. But if you already know the basics of HTML & CSS, you should know where to look for...